# More figures with captions a), b), c)

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption

What is wrong with that please?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{1.jpg}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{1.png}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{1.jpg}}
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{1.png}}
    \caption{(a) blah (b) blah (c) blah (d) blah}
    \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I got error: Missing numbers treating as zero and others.

**EDIT after advice**

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{1.jpg}}\ 
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{1.png}}\ 
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{1.jpg}}\ 
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{1.png}}
  \caption{(a) blah (b) blah (c) blah (d) blah}
  \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

`subcaption` package provides `\subcaptionbox` command, `\subfloat` command and `subfigure` environment, so you cannot use `\subfigure` (which is roughly equivalent to `\begin{subfigure}`) alone.

A `\subfloat` example (supported since `subcaption` v1.3):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{example-image}}\ 
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{example-image}}\ 
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{example-image}}\ 
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \caption{(a) blah (b) blah (c) blah (d) blah}
  \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error: `! Undefined control sequence. \subfloat`

Comment: Are you sure it is `subcaption` and not `subfig` for `\subfloat`?

Comment: I add the code I am using now to my question. I think it is the same as you have post.

Comment: @Archie: Which version of the subcaption package do you use?

Comment: Package: subcaption 2016/05/22 v1.1-161

Comment: The code is compilable and the result is good but there is an error.

Comment: @Archie Command `\subfloat` is supported since `subcaption` v1.3 while your local version is v1.1. So either you update (maybe the whole latex distribution) to the latest version, or use `\subcaptionbox` which shares a similar syntax with `\subfloat`.